# docker-compose: create named volume as specific user

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here's a minimal `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  foo:
    user: "${UID}:${GID}"
    image: node:latest
    container_name: foo
    working_dir: /var/www/foo
    volumes:
      - bar:/var/www/foo/bar

volumes:
  bar:
```

After running `docker-compose up` the named volume is created at `/var/lib/docker/volumes/project_bar`, and the `project_bar` directory is owned by `root` - this is fine. Although the `_data` directory inside it is *also* own by `root` - I would like it to be own by a specific, non-root user.

For example:

```
docker-compose run --rm foo sh -c "mkdir bar/foo"
```

will fail with `mkdir: cannot create directory 'bar/foo': Permission denied`.

I was under the impression that specifying `user: "${UID}:${GID}"` (note: `uid`/`gid` are available to `docker`, exported in shell they are) will solve this. Obviously, I was wrong.

Is there a way to have `/var/lib/docker/volumes/project_bar/_data` being own by specific user? Without `chown`'ing anything if possible. And without involving `Dockerfile`.

EDIT: To clarify, I would like `/var/www/foo/bar` in the container *and* its equivalent in `/var/lib/docker/volumes` to be owned by a specific, not root user.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are either involving the Dockerfile, or you need to setup the volume with a separate process. The named volume will be initialized with the contents of the image, including files, directories, owners, and permissions. This happens when the volume is empty or non-existent.

So your options include:

- update the image to include the desired ownership of that directory. Note if the image defines this as a volume, your change must preced that definition.
- create a volume in advance with the desired ownership and mount that in the container
- modify the entrypoint of the container to run as root, fix the permissions, and then switch to the desired user (using something like gosu)

---

Expanding on the second option, you can create a volume with the desired ownership and content by running a temporary container to do the task:

```
docker container run --rm -v bar-data:/data busybox /bin/sh -c \
  "touch /data/.initialized && chown -R ${UID}:${GID} /data"
```

Then in your compose file you can declare that volume as external:

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  foo:
    user: "${UID}:${GID}"
    image: node:latest
    container_name: foo
    working_dir: /var/www/foo
    volumes:
      - bar:/var/www/foo/bar

volumes:
  bar:
    # tell compose this volume is externally created with a different name
    external: true
    name: bar-data
```

That will create a volume with a single file, needed to prevent docker from reinitializing an empty volume from the image contents. This also means you need to load any data you want in the volume since it will be otherwise empty. A common method to copy data into a volume involves using tar:

```
tar -cC source_dir . | \
  docker run --rm -i -v foo-data:/target busybox tar -xC /target
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your second point? It sounds like something that might work for me. Specifically, how would I create a volume in advance own by `uid`/`gid` specified via exported shell variables? And how do I later tell `docker-compose.yml` to use it? Thanks!